# Finding Asymptotics for a Series

Tags: asymptotics

How can I find a simple expression that's asymptotic to $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2^i/i$?

That is,

```
Sum[2^i/i,{i,1,n-1}].
```

According to https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/AsymptoticBehaviorOfAFunction.html, I can use

```
mainTerm[expr /. x -> 1/x, x]
```

However, when I insert their example

```
mainTerm[(x^2+1)/(1+x), x]
```

the output I receive is exactly the same as the input instead of $x$.

Is there a command that will give the main term?

Comment: Are you talking about the asymptotic behaviour of that sum as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Am I missing something, or is that sum divergent?

Comment: For each fixed $n$ I would like the main term of the sum.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry, completely misunderstood.

Answer (score 4):

As @DanielLichtblau says, Mathematica can do the symbolic sum in terms of [`LerchPhi`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LerchPhi):

```
sum = Sum[2^i/i, {i, n}]
```

> -I ([Pi] - I 2^(1 + n) LerchPhi[2, 1, 1 + n])

It seems that Mathematica can't do the asymptotic expansion:

```
Series[sum, {n, Infinity, 0}]
```

> -I ([Pi] - I E^SeriesData[n, 
>   DirectedInfinity[1], {
>   Log[2], 
>   Log[2]}, -1, 2, 1] LerchPhi[2, 1, 1 + n])

However, you can use [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue) to figure out the asymptotics. Here is what [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue) says about [`LerchPhi`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LerchPhi):

```
ev = Entity["MathematicalFunction", "LerchPhi"]["AsymptoticExpansions"];
ev //InputForm

(* {Function[{\[FormalZ], \[FormalS], \[FormalA]}, Inactivate[ConditionalExpression[
    LerchPhi[\[FormalZ], \[FormalS], \[FormalA]] \[Proportional] (-(1/\[FormalZ]))*Sum[1/((\[FormalA] - \[FormalK] - 1)^\[FormalS]*\[FormalZ]^\[FormalK]), 
        {\[FormalK], 0, Infinity}] + (Log[-\[FormalZ]]^(\[FormalS] - 1)/((-\[FormalZ])^\[FormalA]*(2*Gamma[\[FormalS]])))*
       (2*Pi*Csc[\[FormalA]*Pi] + (Gamma[\[FormalS]] - 1)*(PolyGamma[(1 + \[FormalA])/2] - 
          PolyGamma[\[FormalA]/2])) + (Log[-\[FormalZ]]^(\[FormalS] - 2)/((-\[FormalZ])^\[FormalA]*(2*Gamma[\[FormalS]])))*
       Sum[((2^(\[FormalK] + 1)/(\[FormalK] + 1))*(BernoulliB[\[FormalK] + 1, 1 - \[FormalA]/2] - 
            BernoulliB[\[FormalK] + 1, (1 - \[FormalA])/2]) + (-1)^\[FormalK]*(\[FormalS] - 1)*Gamma[\[FormalS]]*
           Pochhammer[2 - \[FormalS], \[FormalK]]*2^(-\[FormalK] - 1)*(Zeta[\[FormalK] + 2, \[FormalA]/2] - 
            Zeta[\[FormalK] + 2, (\[FormalA] + 1)/2]))/Log[-\[FormalZ]]^\[FormalK], {\[FormalK], 0, Infinity}], 
    (Abs[\[FormalZ]] -> Infinity) && Re[\[FormalA]] > 0 && Re[\[FormalS]] > 0]]], 
 Function[{\[FormalZ], \[FormalS], \[FormalA]}, Inactivate[ConditionalExpression[
    LerchPhi[\[FormalZ], \[FormalS], \[FormalA]] \[Proportional] (1/Gamma[\[FormalS]])*
      (Sum[((Gamma[\[FormalS], (\[FormalA] - \[FormalK] - 1)*Log[-\[FormalZ]]] - Gamma[\[FormalS]])/(\[FormalA] - \[FormalK] - 1)^\[FormalS])*
         \[FormalZ]^(-\[FormalK] - 1), {\[FormalK], 0, Infinity}] + (Log[-\[FormalZ]]^(\[FormalS] - 1)/((-\[FormalZ])^\[FormalA]*2))*
        (PolyGamma[(\[FormalA] + 1)/2] - PolyGamma[\[FormalA]/2] + 
         Sum[(Binomial[\[FormalS] - 1, \[FormalK]]*\[FormalK]!*(Zeta[\[FormalK] + 1, \[FormalA]/2] - 
             Zeta[\[FormalK] + 1, (\[FormalA] + 1)/2]))/(2^\[FormalK]*Log[-\[FormalZ]]^\[FormalK]), 
          {\[FormalK], 1, Infinity}])), (Abs[\[FormalZ]] -> Infinity) && Re[\[FormalA]] > 0 && 
     Re[\[FormalS]] > 0]]], Function[{\[FormalZ], \[FormalS], \[FormalA]}, 
  Inactivate[ConditionalExpression[LerchPhi[\[FormalZ], \[FormalS], \[FormalA]] \[Proportional] 
     1/((\[FormalA]^2)^(\[FormalS]/2)*(1 - \[FormalZ])) + 
      Sum[((((-1)^\[FormalK]*Pochhammer[\[FormalS], \[FormalK]])/\[FormalK]!)*PolyLog[-\[FormalK], \[FormalZ]])/\[FormalA]^\[FormalK], 
        {\[FormalK], 1, Infinity}]/(\[FormalA]^2)^(\[FormalS]/2), Abs[\[FormalA]] -> Infinity]]]} *)
```

It is the third expansion that is of interest. Let's extract it, and use it for the [`LerchPhi`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LerchPhi) object:

```
asymp = Activate[
    ev[[3]][2, 1, n],
    ConditionalExpression | LerchPhi | Pochhammer | PolyLog | DirectedInfinity |
    Abs | Times | Power | Proportional
];
asymp /. \[FormalK] -> i //TeXForm
```

> $\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\Phi (2,1,n)\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}
>    (1+-2)}+\frac{\underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{(-1)^i n^{-i} (1)_i
>    \text{Li}_{-i}(2)}{i!}}{\sqrt{n^2}},\left| n\right| \to \infty \right]$

We are interested in the limit `Abs[n] -> Infinity`:

```
asymp = asymp /. _Rule -> True;
asymp /. \[FormalK] -> i //TeXForm
```

> $\Phi (2,1,n)\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2} (1+-2)}+\frac{\underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty
>    }{\sum }}\frac{(-1)^i n^{-i} (1)_i \text{Li}_{-i}(2)}{i!}}{\sqrt{n^2}}$

I will use the above relation to define:

```
lerchSeries[k_, n_] := Evaluate[Activate[asymp[[2]] /. Infinity->k]]
```

Let's compare the asymptotics of `lerchSeries` and `LerchPhi[2, 1, n+1]`:

```
z = 10`30^2;
LerchPhi[2, 1, z+1] //Chop
lerchSeries[10, z+1]

z = 10`30^3;
LerchPhi[2, 1, z+1] //Chop
lerchSeries[10, z+1]

z = 10`30^4;
LerchPhi[2, 1, z+1] //Chop
lerchSeries[10, z+1]

z = 10`30^5;
LerchPhi[2, 1, z+1] //Chop
lerchSeries[10, z+1]
```

> -0.01010313809318820225350918612
>
> -0.0101031380931847134629924527375
>
> -0.00100100301307554573084602616
>
> -0.00100100301307554573084602289673
>
> -0.00010001000300130075054146877
>
> -0.000100010003001300750541468773477
>
> -0.0000100001000030001300075005
>
> -0.0000100001000030001300075005410468

I think the agreement is pretty good. So, the asymptotics of the sum is:

```
sum /. LerchPhi[2, 1, n+1] -> lerchSeries[10, n+1] //TeXForm
```

> $-i \left(\pi -i 2^{n+1}
>    \left(\frac{-\frac{2}{n+1}-\frac{6}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{26}{(n+1)^3}-\frac{150}{(n+1)^4}
>    -\frac{1082}{(n+1)^5}-\frac{9366}{(n+1)^6}-\frac{94586}{(n+1)^7}-\frac{1091670}{(n+
>    1)^8}-\frac{14174522}{(n+1)^9}-\frac{204495126}{(n+1)^{10}}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2}}-\frac{
>    1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2}}\right)\right)$

or:

```
Series[sum /. LerchPhi[2, 1, n+1] -> lerchSeries[10, n+1], {n, Infinity, 10}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(\frac{1}{n}+\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+\frac{3}{n^3}+\frac{13}{n^4}+\frac{75}{n^
>    5}+\frac{541}{n^6}+\frac{4683}{n^7}+\frac{47293}{n^8}+\frac{545835}{n^9}+\frac{7087
>    261}{n^{10}}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{11}\right)\right) \exp \left(\log (2)
>    n+\log (2)+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{11}\right)\right)-i \pi$

Answer (score 3):

If nothing else, could check numerically against `2^n/Log[n]`. The sum (up to `n`, so adjust for `n-1`) is very close to twice that amount:

```
Table[
 Sum[2.^i/Log[i], {i, 2, n}]/(2^n/Log[n]), {n, 2^Range[2, 15]}]

(* Out[178]= {2.13092975357, 2.18572875976, 2.05561015766, \
2.01956402945, 2.00779127691, 2.00327514385, 2.00142027015, \
2.00062860862, 2.00028230998, 2.000128198777713, 2.00005873009977, \
2.00002709994678, 2.00001258069176, 2.00000587066159} *)
```

--- edit ---

The actual summand is `2^i/i`. This sum has an exact form in terms of the `LerchPhi` function but that one is not so amenable to direct expansion using `Series`. So we will approximate the sum with an integral and see how that behaves.

integral = Integrate[2^i/i, {i, 1, n}, Assumptions -> n > 1]

```
(* Out[209]= -ExpIntegralEi[Log[2]] + ExpIntegralEi[n Log[2]] *)

ser = Series[integral, {n, Infinity, 1}];
Refine[Normal[ser], Assumptions -> n > 1]

(* Out[216]= -ExpIntegralEi[Log[2]] + 2^n/(n Log[2]) *)
```

So the integral is `O(2^n/n)`. Some numerical testing indicates the sum is as well. This could also be shown by noting that the difference between successive summands and successive integrals from `n-1` to `n` is asymptotically a constant fraction of the summand.

```
diff = Integrate[2^i/i, {i, n - 1, n}, Assumptions -> n > 2] - 2^n/n;
approxdiff = 
 Together[Refine[
   Normal[Series[diff, {n, Infinity, 1}, Assumptions -> n > 2]], 
   Assumptions -> n > 2]]

(* Out[229]= -((2^(-1 + n) (-1 + 2 Log[2]))/(n Log[2])) *)
```

--- end edit ---

Comment: Sorry, I edited. I didn't mean for the denominator to be    Log[i]. What expression would we obtain from your output?

Answer (score 2):

Some things change to better. In 12.2 on Windows 10Pro

```
AsymptoticSum[2^i/i, {i, 1, n - 1}, {n, Infinity, 1}]
```

> `-2 + 2^n/n`